# How to define a variable in Oracle Service Bus?

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus

How can I define a variable in a *proxy service* and what is the scope of a variable?

Answer (score 3):

You use an Assign action in the Pipeline.

The scope of that variable is for the PipelinePairNode (Request, Response, and Route).

Answer (score 2):

Use "Assign" from "message processing" design palette. In the properties of "Assign", give any name to that variable in the "variable" property and in "expression" property give the expression of where it would reside..suppose i create a variable named x in body, then in expression i'll give `$body`.

**Scope**: Scope of this Assign resource is within the pipeline pair in which it is defined.